# Print out last two lines of a string word by word

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a script where it prints out the string word by word, and I'm wondering if you have like a string with 10 lines, how do you show the first 8 lines right away, and the last 2 lines you print it out word by word. Thanks.

```
<div id="myTypingText"></div>

<script>
var myString = "Place your <br> string data <br> here, and as much as you like.";
var myArray = myString.split("");
var loopTimer;
function frameLooper() {
    if(myArray.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
    } else {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer); 
                return false;
    }
    loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',70);
}
frameLooper();
</script>
```

Comment: Please be aware that `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />`, `<br foo="bar"/>` is a _HTML line break_ but not an actual new line in the _String_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .split("\n") to split by the new-line character first and print the first 8 items in the array returned then continue with what you have for the remaining text to print it word by word. You can either merge the remaining strings using + or repeatedly run your code on each string in the array.

This is assuming that users are going to be entering input using the keyboard, thus making new lines using then \n new-line character. If the new lines are made some other way, simply use .split() on whatever other character the new lines are separated by and do the same thing.

Comment: Check out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOWbyK
Enter some text into the textarea and hit the button to see if that's what you were looking for.